# Data from chrome storage

Tags: google-chrome, get, synchronization, set, storage

How do i retrieve data from *chrome.storage.sync.set*  and place it in new variable?

```
var marke = 'value1';

chrome.storage.sync.set({myKey: marke}, function() {
    alert('saved');
  });

chrome.storage.sync.get('first', function(e) {
        console.log(e.first)
  });
```

I can console.log it, but don't know how to place it in different variable  or use it elsewhere